# How to Serialize Collection to Json but with class name preceding each instance

Tags: json, .net-core, serialization

I have the following Class Structure in my ASP.Net Core 3.1 application:

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public BodyModel Body { get; set; }
    public List<EmailAddress> ToRecipients { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

which serializes as follows:

```
{
    "subject": "tba",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "the content"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "address": "name1@example.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "address": "name2@example.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

But what I need it to serialize to is the following (each emailAddress element is named):

```
{
    "subject": "tba",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "the content"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "",
                "address": "name1@example.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "",
                "address": "name2@example.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this (am happy to use either `System.Text.Json` OR `Newtonsoft`, whichever is easier)

Comment: can't you just create a new model to represent the end-result you want?

Comment: But I thought that's what I had?  What model would result in the desired output?

Comment: Take your data structure at the bottom, go to https://json2csharp.com/ and paste it in and click "Convert". That will give you the model you'd want. You probably want to check the checkbox `Use JsonPropertyName (.NET Core)` or `Add JsonProperty Attributes` for newtonsoft.

Comment: Wow that did it thanks...didn't know about that site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by @Andy, consider just having a model which reflects Json, because it would be much more intuitive approach.

Otherwise, with `Newtonsoft.Json` you can customize serialization of elements of a collection using [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute with `ItemConverterType` property. And implementing a custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) class, like:

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public BodyModel Body { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(NestingEmailAddressConverter))]
    public List<EmailAddress> ToRecipients { get; set; }
}

public class NestingEmailAddressConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject o = new JObject();
        o.Add("emailAddress", JToken.FromObject(value));
        o.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(EmailAddress);
    }

    public override bool CanRead => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Called as `Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented));` produces target Json.